# Converting column names of a dataframe based on a table

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have dataframe like this

```
   100  101  102
1  0.5  0.1  0.2 
2  0.3  0.4  0.5
3  0.1  0.1  0.1
```

and a table like this:

```
1 100 a
2 101 b
3 102 c
```

What I want is:

```
   a    b     c
1  0.5  0.1  0.2 
2  0.3  0.4  0.5
3  0.1  0.1  0.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll borrow @AmiTavory's assumption that the second frame has columns `x` and `y` (it's trivially changed).  We can use the `rename` method and the `columns` argument:

```
>>> df_new = df0.rename(columns=dict(zip(df1.x, df1.y)))
>>> df_new
     a    b    c
1  0.5  0.1  0.2
2  0.3  0.4  0.5
3  0.1  0.1  0.1
```

This works because we can use a dictionary mapping old to new names for `columns`:

```
>>> dict(zip(df1.x, df1.y))
{100: 'a', 101: 'b', 102: 'c'}
```

Comment: This method is so much faster and elegant! Thanks!

Comment: This *is* a nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your 2nd DataFrame is missing the column names, so in this answer I called them `x` and `y`; that is I assume the 2nd DataFrame is:

```
>> df1
     x  y
0  100  a
1  101  b
2  102  c
```

Furthermore, I assume the first DataFrame is `df0`.

---

You can do so with

```
df0.columns = [df1[df1.x == c].y.values[0] for c in df0.columns]
```

Explanation:

- `df1[df1.x == c].y.values[0]` finds the value in the `y` column corresponding to `c` in the `x` column.
- `[... for c in df0.columns]` does that for all columns names in `df0`.
- `df0.columns = ...` assigns the result to be the new column names of `df0`.